# British vs. USA grammar: Wasn't or Weren't usage

Tags: grammar

From a British speaker, "I hope you wasn't too late." In the USA we would say "weren't". Was this poor grammar, or is this acceptable in the UK?  I immediately thought it wrong; however, I don't want to be too presumptuous.

Comment: No, it's ungrammatical in the UK in Standard English.

Comment: ... but to clarify @BillJ's comment, it is 'grammatical' (it's just the common way of saying things) in certain communities (those, you might say, don't speak 'well'). It's just a different way of speaking. You may pass judgement on those communities for not speaking _your_ version and cal them 'wrong', but it's how they speak (and it's just a different rule). Of course, you don't want to use this in school, work, or anything but very informal contexts using standard English (US, UK, Aus, etc).

Comment: Thank you for these responses.  I wondered if it were colloquial, or if it was simply driven by poor intellect. As an engineer I am a bit of a perfectionist and when considering hiring someone to represent my company, I want them to be literate.  This clearly bothered me since it was written in an email, but since they are in England, I didn't want to be too judgmental.

Comment: Written in an email... *ouch* ... bad news for the candidate, who sounds who might be a Londoner. That is someone who writes as they speak and  I think it would have been easily overlooked had it been uttered in fact speech but in writing, the error screams out.